# Why wrapper is not glossy

Tags: materials, node-editor

Need help why my wrapper not looks glossy. Well in the preview it looks glossy. Whats missing node or other feature that my wrapper not looks glossy. Any suggestion or help

[[image]

**FINAL RESULT**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you know that an object is reflective? Because you see something reflected on it...

You have a very flat environment, so the reflection is almost homogeneous.

Add some other element that will break the flatness of the scene and that will highlight the reflective properties of your object.

A small light might work, just bring down the intensity of the Environment image

[image]

Do a search online on how to light reflective objects and you will see that the important most important thing is the placement of the reflected elements.

Comment: Thanks looks good. Can u plz show the settings of the plane emission

Comment: Thanks for giving a good suggestion and thats my final result at the top.