# How to achieve steel shiny effect

Tags: materials, light

Im confused with the material. I have a logo below and on top monkey. The logo and the monkey have the same material. Monkey is just i want to check the steel effect. But for the text and the logo there is no steel and shiny effect

[image]

[image]

**This type of result looking for**

[image]

But the monkey look shiny steel or chrome effect will as the below logo and the text doesn't. What else i have to do achieve the steel shiny effect for the logo and text below. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: It is shiny, it just don't have anything in particular to reflect. In your camera view logo surface is reflecting plain backdrop.

Comment: @LukeD so whats missing or how can i make it reflect.

Comment: Remove backdrop to see that it is reflecting just fine, consider making it a bit different (backdrop), change hdri map or camera angle. Another thing could be to add some normal map to make it a bit bumpy and roughness map to make it less uniform.

Comment: As LukeD has mentioned it is all about "Reflections". The monkey has curved surfaces so it is picking up reflections that your "Flat" logo is not seeing. You can change your background and/or add objects that are out of the cameras view but reflect in the surface of your logo. Lighting your scene with an HDRi would be one possible solution. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4IN4V1SM-A

Comment: @Dontwalk i have added the hdri also but the result is same for me i dont know whats missing

Comment: @Dontwalk i have upload the screenshot its mention that it has the hdri background

Comment: Think of your flat logo as a mirror. Keep in mind light travels in straight lines and that the angle of incedence equals the angle of reflectance. Try a different HDRi that may have an image area that you flat logo will reflect into your camera. There are some good free ones here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_7a0xnPplxRU5VOTVXOVdwZE0/view

Comment: This is not about the material, but about the environment. Highly reflective surfaces will reflect the environment that surrounds them. If all you have is a flat color as background then that is all that will be reflected. Seee: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91146/how-can-i-render-objects-with-very-shiny-surfaces/91173#91173 you had asked a similar question earlier: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88138/why-wrapper-is-not-glossy/88143#88143

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51602/what-lighting-and-background-will-make-a-realistic-gemstone/51622#51622 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50576/1853