# Help me to add glossiness in my file

Tags: rendering, materials

[image: This is an image of toothpaste packet and I have made this using blender.]

I want to plastic type gloss and reflection of light on it.
Please help to add those effect.

Comment: Could you please add more information about your scene setup, render engine and current material?

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88138/why-wrapper-is-not-glossy/88143#88143

Comment: Do you got the answer or want more detail? if yes accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Setup:
[image: Setup]

1. Add a glossy Shader (with roughness: 0)
2. Add Mix Node to combine the material
3. Assign factor of mix node according your need (the more fac creates more gloss!)
4. Add a show light which will be reflected on your model.
5. Play around the position of your mesh light so you can get good angle of reflection.

That's all

[image: Render]